# Need to show same custom list on multiple subsites in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online, is there a way to show the same custom list on multiple subsites?  We have a company Intranet with a separate subsite for each location in five cities.  We want to (1) create a custom News list with a “Location” column with five checkboxes, (2) create a view for each location, and (3) show the appropriate view on each location’s subsite.  Items in the list often apply to two or more locations, hence the checkboxes, so we want to maintain only one list and have each location’s subsite show only what is relevant to them.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to create a `site content` type . Which will be used by those lists across subsites. After that it will be easy to filter out the results based on the content type.

Comment: Thank you Ashish.  We discovered that we can use a Page Viewer with a list or library, not just a page, so that is meeting our needs for now.  Best regards.